# Find column labels in a filtered numpy array from pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, label

I have a pandas data frame which I need to export to numpy to perform some operations. Those operations result in deletion of some of the columns. I would like to compare the resulting numpy array to my original data frame to obtain the labels of the columns which were retained. The problem is, that some of the columns may not be unique...

An example:

1. Create a sample dataframe:

```
>>> loci_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['SNP1','SNP2','SNP3','SNP4','SNP5','SNP6','SNP7','SNP8','SNP9','SNP10'],
...                        data=[[ 0., np.NaN,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
...                                [ 0., np.NaN,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
...                                [ np.NaN, np.NaN,  0.,  2.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0., np.NaN],
...                                [ 0., np.NaN,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
...                                [ 0., np.NaN,  2.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
...                                [ 0., np.NaN,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
...                                [ 0., np.NaN,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
...                                [ 0., np.NaN,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
...                                [ 0., np.NaN,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
...                                [ 0., np.NaN,  0.,  1.,  1., np.NaN,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.]])
>>> loci_df
   SNP1  SNP2  SNP3  SNP4  SNP5  SNP6  SNP7  SNP8  SNP9  SNP10
0   0.0   NaN   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0    0.0
1   0.0   NaN   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   0.0    0.0
2   NaN   NaN   0.0   2.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   0.0    NaN
3   0.0   NaN   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   0.0    0.0
4   0.0   NaN   2.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   0.0    0.0
5   0.0   NaN   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0
6   0.0   NaN   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0    0.0
7   0.0   NaN   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   0.0    0.0
8   0.0   NaN   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0    0.0
9   0.0   NaN   0.0   1.0   1.0   NaN   1.0   1.0   0.0    1.0
```

2. Move it to a numpy array and perform some operations - here removing columns where all values are missing, or all non-missing values are equal.

```
>>> loci = np.array(loci_df)
>>> m1 = np.isnan(loci)
>>> m2 = loci[0]==loci
>>> loci = loci[:,~(m1|m2).all(0)]
>>> loci
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1., nan],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1., nan,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

What I would now like to get is the list of labels in the original data frame which were retained after filtering in numpy.

```
['SNP3', 'SNP4', 'SNP5', 'SNP6', 'SNP7', 'SNP8', 'SNP10']
```

Note: some columns may not be unique, e.g. here columns SNP7 and SNP8 have the same values - I want to keep them both! But it means that my (not optimal) approach of using column values as dictionary keys, and column labels as dictionary values is not going to work...

I've tried reading the filtered data into a new data frame and then comparing the original with the resulting one, but not surprisingly I am getting KeyErrors:

```
>>> filtered=pd.DataFrame(data=loci)
>>> filtered
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
2  0.0  2.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN
3  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
4  2.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
5  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
6  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
7  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
8  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
9  0.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0

loci_df.loc[:,np.all(loci_df.values==filtered.values, axis=0)]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jilska2/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: False

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jilska2/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1761, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "/Users/jilska2/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1271, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
  File "/Users/jilska2/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1388, in _getitem_lowerdim
    section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "/Users/jilska2/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1964, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File "/Users/jilska2/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 624, in _get_label
    return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
  File "/Users/jilska2/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3529, in xs
    return self[key]
  File "/Users/jilska2/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Users/jilska2/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: False
```

Is there a way of getting this, or do I need to completely change my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is create mask by chaining both conditions and use for filter columns names in `DataFrame` constructor:

```
loci = np.array(loci_df)
m1 = np.isnan(loci)
m2 = loci[0]==loci

mask = ~(m1|m2).all(0)
loci = loci[:,mask]

print (loci_df.columns[mask])
Index(['SNP3', 'SNP4', 'SNP5', 'SNP6', 'SNP7', 'SNP8', 'SNP10'], dtype='object')

filtered=pd.DataFrame(data=loci, columns=loci_df.columns[mask])
print (filtered)
   SNP3  SNP4  SNP5  SNP6  SNP7  SNP8  SNP10
0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0    0.0
1   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0    0.0
2   0.0   2.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0    NaN
3   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0    0.0
4   2.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0    0.0
5   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0    0.0
6   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0    0.0
7   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0    0.0
8   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0    0.0
9   0.0   1.0   1.0   NaN   1.0   1.0    1.0
```